# How to assign value to global array from inner class

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am working on app in which the app gets data from server and i am trying to assign the data to the global array, but it is not being assigned as I am trying to assign data from inner class. The file is as follows:

```java
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    QuizFormat[] quizFormatArray = new QuizFormat[0];
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        ...
        getTest();
        Log.i("size","Array: "+quizFormatArray.length);
        try {
            for (QuizFormat qf: quizFormatArray) {
                Log.i("que",qf.getQuestion());
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public void getTest(){
        class FetchData extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {
            TestActivity ta = new TestActivity();
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                ll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                try {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);
                    JSONArray testArray = obj.getJSONArray("test");
                    for (int i=0; i<testArray.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject testObj = testArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        JSONObject optionsObj = testObj.getJSONObject("options");
                        
                        String[] options = new String[4];
                        options[0] = optionsObj.getString("opt1");
                        options[1] = optionsObj.getString("opt2");
                        options[2] = optionsObj.getString("opt3");
                        options[3] = optionsObj.getString("opt4");
                        
                        ta.quizFormatArray = Arrays.copyOf(ta.quizFormatArray,ta.quizFormatArray.length+1);
                        ta.quizFormatArray[ta.quizFormatArray.length-1] = new QuizFormat(testObj.getInt("que_id"),
                                                                                        testObj.getString("question"),
                                                                                        options,
                                                                                        testObj.getString("answer"));
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        FetchData fd = new FetchData();
        fd.execute();
    }
}
```

`QuizFormatArray` is a POJO class which has quiz attributes with getters, setters and parameterized constructors as follows:

```java
public class QuizFormat {
    int id;
    String question;
    String[] options;
    String answer;

    public QuizFormat(int id, String question, String[] options, String answer) {
        this.id = id;
        this.question = question;
        this.options = options;
        this.answer = answer;
    }
    
    //Getters and Setters   
    ...
}
```

I am checking the value of array in logcat, but it is showing 0, that means no elements are inserted.
I have tried

1. replacing `Array` with `ArrayList`
2. creating separate method in class `TestActivity` to receive the array from inner class and assign it to global array
   but none of the above worked. How can i assign the value to global array?

Comment: why does every `FetchData` have its own `TestActivity ta`?

Comment: @luk2302 I just tried it to make sure it is referred to the correct array, just to be on a safe side, bt still not working

Comment: No, you are doing the exact opposite of that, the line ensures that you **always** reference the wrong array because you never interact with the array of the activity that actually invokes the `getTest`.

Comment: @luk2302 I just tried it without creating the object and directly referring the array by its name `quizFormatArray`, but not a luck

Comment: @luk2302 any tips for how to achieve that?